# Was General Doolittle involved in the invention of RP-1?

Tags: fuel, naca

[James Doolittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Doolittle) is most famous for leading the 1942 air raid on Tokyo.  However, between the world wars, he earned a doctorate in aeronautical engineering from MIT, became the manager of Shell Oil's aviation division, and [befriended Robert Goddard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Doolittle#U.S._space_program).  After World War II, he returned to Shell Oil as an executive, and was the [last chairman of NACA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Advisory_Committee_for_Aeronautics#Chairmen), the predecessor agency to NASA.  He [turned down an offer](https://www.airspacemag.com/space/i-was-there-the-tremendous-potential-of-rocketry-18946468/?page=2) to serve as NASA's first administrator.

Considering his leadership positions in both Shell Oil and NACA, **did Doolittle have any involvement in the invention of RP-1 rocket fuel?**